# DB2 information center cannot be started in Windows 7 - NUMA error

Tags: java, windows-7, db2, numa

I downloaded the DB2 Information Center, then I unzipped and started. However, there was a crash at this time, and the application never started. It created a dump file in the directory. The javacore file contains this part:

```
3XHCPUARCH       Architecture   : x86
3XHNUMCPUS       How Many       : 2
3XHNUMASUP       NUMA is either not supported or has been disabled by user
```

What does it mean? I searched in Google, and I found something about /usepmtimer in the boot.ini file, however, Windows 7 does not have this file.
What can I do in order to use the Information Center locally in Windows 7?

Comment: The line about NUMA is not necessarily your error message. There should be more in the dump than that. Uninstall and reinstall to see if the error is reproducible. Post the entire dump with all the error codes for better assistance.

Comment: ...before reinstalling make sure you meet all the pre-reqs

Comment: This is the stand alone version of the info centre, and I just extracted the files, and execute the .bat file in Windows. It does not have an installation, and I think this should load something related with Eclipse. That means, that reinstalling is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this does not solve the problem, but at least it permits to execute the Information Center locally as standalone.

I looked at the ic-wrkstn-start.bat file, and I saw that there is only one line in the line, the rest are comments. This line executes the given Java Runtime Environment, and it seems that the problem is there.

The given JRE is a IBM J9 and I think the problem is there. Only by calling this binary with the option version, the output gives the same error:

```
\db2_v97_nt32_workstation_infocenter>jre\bin\java.exe -version
Unhandled exception
Type=Floating point error vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00080020 ExceptionCode=c0000094 ExceptionAddress=001F3B0B ContextFlags=0001003f
Handler1=00389A50 Handler2=001E95C0
EDI=00000000 ESI=00000000 EAX=00000004 EBX=0061CA70
ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
EIP=001F3B0B ESP=0066F80C EBP=0054AE10 EFLAGS=00210246
Module=C:\Users\angoca\Downloads\db2_v97_nt32_workstation_infocenter\jre\bin\J9PRT24.dll
Module_base_address=001E0000 Offset_in_DLL=00013b0b
Target=2_40_20080816_022093_lHdSMr (Windows Vista 6.1 build 7601 Service Pack 1)
CPU=x86 (2 logical CPUs) (0x6eae7000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
j9port_init_library:0x001F3B0B [0x001E6280 +0x0000D88B]
0x0061CA70
---------------------------------------
JVMDUMP006I Traitement de l'événement de dump en cours "gpf", détails "" - Veuillez patienter.
JVMDUMP007I JVM demande un dump System en utilisant 'C:\Users\angoca\Downloads\db2_v97_nt32_workstation_infocenter\core.20111015.014542.5588.0001.dmp'
JVMDUMP010I Dump System écrit dans C:\Users\angoca\Downloads\db2_v97_nt32_workstation_infocenter\core.20111015.014542.5588.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP007I JVM demande un dump Snap en utilisant 'C:\Users\angoca\Downloads\db2_v97_nt32_workstation_infocenter\Snap.20111015.014542.5588.0002.trc'
JVMDUMP010I Dump Snap écrit dans C:\Users\angoca\Downloads\db2_v97_nt32_workstation_infocenter\Snap.20111015.014542.5588.0002.trc
JVMDUMP007I JVM demande un dump Java en utilisant 'C:\Users\angoca\Downloads\db2_v97_nt32_workstation_infocenter\javacore.20111015.014542.5588.0003.txt'
JVMDUMP013I Evénement de dump traité "gpf", détails "".
```

Well, as you can see, the error is not the Info Center, but it is the given Java. For this reason, I just took my installed JRE, the Oracle (Sun) one, and it worked.

Instead of execute 'jre\bin\java', I put 'java', and the installed (path) java will be used.

Comment: Anyway, there should be a problem with IBM J9 in Windows 7, or in the given db2 version, but it is a little out my scope.

Answer (score 0):

Some steps you can try out:

- Install newest fixpack level
- Make sure you are using 64-bit installer for 64-bit platform, and 32-bit installer for 32-bit platform
- Make sure "java --version" returns something sane
- Add -Xint to the startup parameters of the JVM for the infocenter

Comment: Why a fixpack? this is the info center, and it does not have anything to do with db2 udb. Or it does?

Yes, I have the correct version, my computer is a 64-bits processor, and I have the corresponding version.

Java, well, I have Java 7 well installed, however the info center uses its own java (probably j9). Anyway, it returns the right version.

I will try to find how to modify the stater and put the -Xint